# How can I connect to an SMB share on a Mac behind a router?

Tags: macos, router, smb

I'm trying to SMB access a Mac (macOS 10.13.6) located behind a router. For that, I forwarded the Mac's internal port 445 to the external port 12345.

Now, when I connect via smb://[username]@[external IP]:12345 , I do get a login prompt like I should, but after that:

"There was a problem connecting to the server “x.x.x.x”." "Check the server name or IP address, and then try again. If you continue to have problems, contact your system administrator."
[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEaED.png)

What could be the problem?

Thanks,

geb

Comment: I also tried disabling both the Mac's and the router's firewall, to no avail.

Comment: Update: I tried the same thing with afp (port 548) instead, and that worked perfectly right away! Is there a downside to this? And, is this somehow encrypted? I guess not.